How to use zone.js in non angular tests?
We're developing a UI application using vanilla JS and browser APIs.  This has been a little tedious but otherwise fine so far.
However, now we're developing some more complex UIs that react to scroll and resize events. While testing such lib, we currently cause some element in the DOM to scroll/resize and then wait for some hard-coded amount of time e.g. 100ms.
it('does something', async () => {
  const [element, otherElement] = await someSetup();
  expect(element).isAlignedWith(otherElement);

  element.parentElement!.scrollTop -= 100;
  await delay(100); // Wait for the scroll events to be processed.

  expect(element).isStillAlignedWith(otherElement);
});

This isn't ideal because sometimes the timeout ends up being too little and our tests become flaky and other times it is too long, slowing down the entire test suite.
Is it possible to use fake zones in non-angular tests somehow and simply flush() all events in the task queue and then assert our expectations.

For now this looks not as question but a Jira task. Have u tried anything so far?

What does this have to do with Angular or AngularJS?
